# Cannot find labels with that class

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an array called "arrayRestado1" from which I want to extract the first element and save that value in the value property of an html input. If it extracts the value but, it does not find the input with that class so the input does not show anything.

The code is in JavaScript:

`const col1_f1 = document.getElementsByClassName("col1_f1").value = arrayRestado1[0]`
`console.log(col1_f1)`

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection, not a single element, so you can't set its value. Do you want to set the value of the first instance of that collection? Your browser dev tools should show an error.

Comment: Please post your entire code, not just a snippet.

Answer (score 2):

the function `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements (an HTML Collection to be correct), not only a single DOM element.

Here's the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

So with your current code you could try this:

```
const col1_f1 = document.getElementsByClassName("col1_f1")[0].value = arrayRestado1[0]
console.log(col1_f1)
```

See the `[0]` after the function? This means we want the first element of the array. Doesn't matter if there is only one with the given class name `col1_f1`.

Otherwise you could give your inputs/elemets specific (unique) ids and then use the `document.getElementById()` function to get them as single elements "directly" in the first place.

More on that here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Have a good day!

Nico

Comment: Thank you very much Nico, your knowledge helped me